# preg_match start and end of string and replace

Tags: php, laravel

Could someone help with a preg_match expression I need it to match the - dash character at the start and end of a string. This is for tags e.g. match -my-tag- should then be my-tag so It only  matches the start and end of a string and replace it the characters with and empty string

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with this easy expression:

```
$string = "-my-tag-";
$tag = preg_replace("/^-(.*)-$/", "$1", $string);
```

`^` and `$` are used to match the start and the end of the string, while `(.*)` captures every other symbols.

You can read more about regular expressions in the official [PHP Documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).

Comment: Oh also could you replace any white spaces aswell for me please

Comment: Saying, "Thanks!  And by the way, how could I remove whitespace?" would be better than asking the question how you asked it.

Comment: @KDM you can use `str_replace` on the tag string, before passing it to the regular expression, like this `$tag = preg_replace("/^-(.*)-$/", "$1", str_replace(' ', ''. $string));`